# Angular-formly inline validation of three related fields not showing errors correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-formly

When selling an item for a customer there are guidelines on how the price can be set, basically this consists of three elements:

Minimum - the lowest price it can be sold for

Preferred - the price the customer would like us to sell it for

Maximum - the highest price it could be sold for

I have an angular-formly form defined with three fields that validate on model change (and am also using ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }") but errors are being displayed incorrectly:

Initial settings:

```
Minimum                    Preferred                   Maximum
10                         20                          30
```

Change minimum to 101 gives correctly (on loss of focus):

```
Minimum                    Preferred                   Maximum
101                        20                          30
Cannot be greater
than preferred
```

Change preferred to 201 gives correctly (on loss of focus):

```
Minimum                    Preferred                   Maximum
101                        201                         30
                           Cannot be less than
                           minimum or greater
                           than maximum
```

Change maximum to 301 gives *incorrectly* (on loss of focus):

```
Minimum                    Preferred                   Maximum
101                        201                         301
                           Cannot be less than
                           minimum or greater
                           than maximum
```

There are numerous configurations that can be entered that result in an incorrect message being displayed.

What I would like it to do is display an error when the field is in error and clear it when it isn't!

I have also noticed that errors won't display until the control has lost focus then after that they display as the user interacts with the control or any of the other controls.  Why is it necessary for the control to lose focus before errors are shown?

This is best demonstrated by playing with the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aFks9XFDNJAvDfRFDLya?p=preview

Validation methods are shown below:

```
vm.fields = [
              {
            className: "panel-body",
            fieldGroup: [
                {
                    className: "form-row row",
                    fieldGroup: [
                        {
                            key: 'MinimumPrice',
                            className: "col-xs-3",
                            type: 'input',
                            templateOptions: {
                                label: 'Minimum',
                                required: true,
                                maxlength: 3,
                                minlength: 1
                            },
                            extras: {
                                validateOnModelChange: true
                            },
                            validators: {
                                Price: {
                                    expression: function validatePrice($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
                                        var viewValue = parseInt($viewValue, 10);
                                        var isValid = viewValue <= scope.model.PreferredPrice;
                                        return isValid;
                                    },
                                    message: '"Cannot be greater than preferred"'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            key: 'PreferredPrice',
                            className: "col-xs-3",
                            type: 'input',
                            templateOptions: {
                                label: 'Preferred',
                                required: true,
                                maxlength: 3,
                                minlength: 1
                            },
                            extras: {
                                validateOnModelChange: true
                            },
                            validators: {
                                Price: {
                                    expression: function validatePrice($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
                                        var viewValue = parseInt($viewValue, 10);
                                        if (viewValue < scope.model.MinimumPrice) return false;
                                        if (viewValue > scope.model.MaximumPrice) return false;
                                        return true;
                                    },
                                    message: '"Cannot be less than minimum or greater than maximum"'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            key: 'MaximumPrice',
                            className: "col-xs-3",
                            type: 'input',
                            templateOptions: {
                                label: 'Maximum',
                                required: true,
                                maxlength: 3,
                                minlength: 1
                            },
                            extras: {
                                validateOnModelChange: true
                            },
                            validators: {
                                Price: {
                                    expression: function validatePrice($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
                                        var viewValue = parseInt($viewValue, 10);
                                        return viewValue >= scope.model.PreferredPrice;
                                    },
                                    message: '"Cannot be less than preferred"'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }];
```

Comment: On loss of focus , it doesn't throw up an error?[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LchqegYfppug3fZ8oPJi?p=preview)

Comment: Yes it throws an error on loss of focus but doesn't clear an error when the field is no longer invalid.

Comment: Weird, in some cases it did clear the error , in some tries it didn't.